# Adjective for "on the scale of a building"

Tags: word-choice

Municipal means roughly "of the city" or "on the scale of the city."

Is there a word for "of the building" or "on the scale of the building"?

For example, wifi provided by the city is municipal wifi. Wifi provided by the apartment or office building is **_** wifi -- fill in the blank please!

*edit: This is not a wifi-specific question, as some respondents have understandably assumed. The actual use I'm looking for is for a building-wide network of accelerometers installed in the concrete for structural health monitoring.*

Comment: You could go with "erection" wifi.

Comment: "Local" or "business-centric" wifi?

Comment: I think most of the answers would work just as well for things other than wifi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a word but it ought to be: "edificial"

Medieval latin "municipium" means a "free city" i.e. one not under the control of any feudal lord. "edificium" means a building, a structure. (a construction worker is an "edifex" for instance).

So the wifi for the whole building could be the edificial wifi.

Beware that only latin nerds are going to get that.

Comment: Wow, I'm really tempted to use this. I'm writing a scientific proposal and it's full of other jargon, so why not invent some more?

Comment: Going to accept this answer because I think edificial is exactly the word I'm looking for, even if it's not a word.

Answer (score 2):

Referring to a general building, what about "premises" wifi?

Comment: I like it, but I guess I'm looking for something that is exclusively an adjective.

Comment: On second thought, "premesis-wide accelerometer network" might work quite well.

Comment: Yes, sounds fine :)

Answer (score 1):

How about using **"on site"** WIFI?

Answer (score 1):

How about simply saying "in-house" or -- even more simply -- ["in-building"](http://www.connect802.com/mdunits.htm) wifi?

Answer (score 0):

If it is just for wifi, then use wifi zone.